# Install ArcGIS Desktop unattended or silently

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation

I’m using the instructions for [Installing ArcGIS Desktop silently](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/get-started/installation-guide/installing-silently.htm). However the process doesn’t always work in unattended mode, because of a prompt about *"The following applications need to be closed before continuing installation: ArcGIS Cache Manager"*. What switch or parameter is needed to auto-select an answer and keep going?

[image]

The current command line:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe /I ^
    "%cd%\ArcGIS_Desktop\Desktop\SetupFiles\setup.msi" ^
    ESRI_LICENSE_HOST=LICENSESERVER ^
    SOFTWARE_CLASS=Viewer ^
    SEAT_PREFERENCE=Float ^
    INSTALLDIR=C:\ArcGIS ^
    INSTALLDIR1=C:\Python27 ^
    DESKTOP_CONFIG=TRUE ^
    ADDLOCAL=ArcMap,ArcCatalog,Python,SpatialAnalyst ^
    /qb
```

Answer (score 6):

Esri Canada's tech support answer:

> In order to automatically have any conflicting applications closed
>   automatically, you will need to create a shell script (bat or vb),
>   check for this process, and kill it before running the silent install.
>   Unfortunately, there is no built-in parameter for this function.
>
> This will include any .exe file in arcgis desktop bin folder,
>   including indexing and arcgis.com connection tools.

After some investigation and testing here's my targeted list of programs to watch for (since blindly testing all .exe's under ArcGIS seems too crude). Please feel free to edit and add new ones.

```
ArcGIS\Desktop10.*\bin\DesktopIndexingService.exe
ArcGIS\Desktop10.*\bin\DesktopThumbnailUpdatingService.exe
ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGISIndexingServer.exe

Common Files\ArcGIS\bin\ArcGISCacheMgr.exe
Common Files\ArcGIS\bin\ArcGISConnection.exe
```

Then from [SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) `pskill` to end the processes (also see `handle` and `pslist`):

```
d:\> pskill ArcGISCacheMgr

PsKill v1.15 - Terminates processes on local or remote systems
Copyright (C) 1999-2012  Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Process ArcGISCacheMgr killed.
```

Batchfile example:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set _kill=DesktopIndexingService DesktopThumbnailUpdatingService ^
    ArcGISIndexingServer ArcGISCacheMgr ArcGISConnection
for %%g in (%_kill%) do (
    pskill /accepteula %%g 2>nul
    )
```

Notes:
`/accepteula` parameter to accept the terms automatically (doing so creates registry key *`HKCU\Software\Sysinternals\{appname}\EulaAccepted`*). *[Thanks sunilalobo](http://forum.sysinternals.com/pstools-are-command-line-tools_topic8792.html)*.

`2>nul` is for cleaner messages, only reporting results and suppressing the copyright info etc.

Comment: nice answer. I am going to hang on to this one.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your circumstatances, one way to circumvent this problem is to use a deployment tool which runs the installation during startup, pausing login until the installation has completed. These prevents any components, such as Cache Manager, from starting and locking any of the files. Personally I use wpkg - see http://wpkg.org/Arcgis10 (the link relates to an earlier version of ArcGIS, but the principals are the same). There are many other choices, both commercial and opensource. ServerFault or SoftwareRecomendations might help you out with this.

Also for a completely silent install use the replace the switch `/qb` with `/qn`
(b=BasicUI, n=No UI, see `msiexec /?` for more details)

Comment: Thanks for tip about *wpkg*, hadn't seen that one yet. Bit about pre-login doesn't apply (to us) because we often have users self-serve the install; we've had too many issues with other deployment tools (e.g. MS System Center, good tool but learning curve too big for part-time sysadmin).